# high order (infinite series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

This question, I have made but there was no answer, so I will try again. If we have  the sums $f(n) = 1^{59} + 2^{59} + 3^{59} + \cdots + (10^n)^{59}$ and $g(n) = 1^{5} + 2^{5} + 3^{5} + \cdots + (10^n)^{5}$. For large enough $n$,
$f(n)$ is approximately $\frac{1}{60} 10^{60n}$ whereas
$g(n)$ is approximately $\frac16 10^{6n}$. In the limited sense$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^{5} + 2^{5} + 3^{5} + \cdots + (10^n)^{5}}
{1^{59} + 2^{59} + 3^{59} + \cdots + (10^n)^{59}} = 0.$$ So both quantities
go toward the same "value",but $f(n) = 1^{59} + 2^{59} + 3^{59} + \cdots + (10^n)^{59}$ will grow
much, much faster than $g(n) = 1^{5} + 2^{5} + 3^{5} + \cdots + (10^n)^{5}$.because  I assume as $n$ tends to infinity,that the sum $f(n) = 1^{59} + 2^{59} + 3^{59} + \cdots + (10^n)^{59}$ go toward the  "value" $16666...0000...$ in other words as $n$ tends to infinity, my guess is that the sum of the sum $f(n) = 1^{59} + 2^{59} + 3^{59} + \cdots + (10^n)^{59}$ must contain infinitely many $6$ and infinitely many $0$ (this can be verified, if $ n$ is large enough $ 6$ and $ 0 $ will start to appear) My assumption is correct ?

Comment: What do you mean "contain"? There is no sense in which $f(n)$ "goes toward" $16666...$ or any value other than infinity. You seem confused on the definition of limit, or the definition of infinity, or the definition of number, or all three. Don't try to "intuit" things about infinity and limits or you will get it all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you mean is this.  Using Faulhaber's formula, 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N i^{59} = \dfrac{N^{60}}{60} + \dfrac{N^{59}}{2} + 
\dfrac{59}{12} N^{58} + O(N^{57})$$
and thus for $N = 10^n$ with $n$ large, the highest-order digits of the sum
are $1 6 \ldots 6 7 1 6 \ldots 671$ with $n-3$ $6$'s in each group. 
Similarly
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N i^5 = \dfrac{N^6}{6} + \dfrac{N^5}{2} + \dfrac{5}{12} N^4 + O(N^3)$$
so the highest-order digits in this sum for $N = 10^n$ are $1 6 \ldots 6716\ldots 670$, with $n-2$ $6$'s in each group.

Comment: thanks (exactly what I mean)